# phpMyAdmin no funciona en Ubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

Instale `Ubuntu 16.04.1` en un ordenador y estoy tratando de instalar un servidor local, ya instale Apache2, php, MySQL y Phpmyadmin. Al abrir el navegador y ingresar la dirección `localhost/phpmyadmin` no encuentra la página.

Ya busque opciones para solucionar el problema sin tener éxito. Alguien puede brindarme información respecto al problema antes mencionado.

Comment: sabes el puerto que utilizas con exactitud? por ejemplo podria ser localhost:8080/phpmyadmin . Revisalo bien en la configuracion.

Comment: intenta con este tutorial [phpMyAdmin installation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-16-04), también puedes agregar detalles a la pregunta (como los pasos de instalación que usaste), ya que es difícil saber que sucede con la información que has proveído.

Comment: Sé que es algo tonto y básico pero... ¿has iniciado Apache2 y MySQL? Es decir, ¿los tienes activos?

Comment: si está iniciados en cuanto al puerto apenas voy a probar a ver si es eso. comentaré sobre el resultado

Comment: Pues no se pudo, ya traté con el tutorial pero me da lo mismo. Ya casi al finalizar arroja un mensaje de error.
An error occurred while installing the database:                           
  │                                                                            
  │ mysql said: mysql: [Warning] mysql: Empty value for 'port' specified.      
  │ Will throw an error in future versions ERROR 1819 (HY000) at line 1:       
  │ Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para instalar phpmyadmin en Ubuntu 16.04 debes ejecutar:

```
apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Durante el proceso te preguntará si quieres gestionar e instalar una base de datos con `dbconfig-common`, tras lo que te pedirá la clave del usuario `root` de la base de datos y una clave (opción, que puedes pasar pulsando <kbd>Enter</kbd> para que genere una aleatoria) para datos internos de la propia aplicación `phpmyadmin` y, por último, si quieres configurarlo en el servidor `apache2` o `lighttpd`.

Te creará una configuración en `/etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf` que puedes activar o desactivar con los comandos `a2enconf phpmyadmin` y `a2disconf phpmyadmin`, **tras lo cual deberás ejecutar una recarga de la configuración servidor `apache2` con el comando `service apache2 reload`**.

Te recomiendo ejecutar ese comando también tras la instalación de `phpmyadmin` o tras modificar cualquier archivo de configuración de `apache2`, instalación de módulos de PHP, etc.

Recuerda instalar previamente el servidor `mysql-server` o la ejecución de `dbconfig-commmon` fallará.

Si por cualquier motivo ignoraste cualquier mensaje de error de instalación y quieres volver a repetir el proceso, usa el comando `dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin`.

Answer (score 2):

Prueba seguir los pasos de [este video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DFjSHp8p9R8).

Yo tenía el mismo problema que tú y hay una parte del video donde te pide usar el comando:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/htmal/phpmyadmin
```

Después de esto recargas el buscador y ya debe de aparecer la página de PHPMyAdmin indicando que funciona tu servidor.

Comment: Gracias Esteban tu respuesta me Ayudo tenia un Error 404 con phpmyadmin y intentaba darle permiso de toda las maneras y tu comando me ayudo gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Es necesario más información al respecto.

¿El servidor puede trabajar con `PHP`? y/o ¿Ya configuraste tu cuenta root de `MySQL`?

Si existe alguna duda de configuración, el siguiente enlace te llevará a un articulo en Ingles que te explica como llevar acabo la instalación de forma correcta: [Link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu)

Respecto a la instalación de phpMyAdmin lo encuentras en el siguiente enlace: [Link](http://www.howopensource.com/2014/09/install-phpmyadmin-in-ubuntu-debian/)

Comment: Ya todo está configurado, ya hice la prueba de función y todo corre perfectamente, excepto el phpmyadmin. Ya he hecho lo mismo algunas otras veces pero en Ubuntu 10.4. Sin embargo en el esta versión no funcionó, seguí todos los pasos, apliqué el mismo procedimiento, incluso después de que no quedó a la primera desinstalé todo, busqué un tutorial y seguí todos los pasos, pero ni así funcionó. El mysql lo probé desde la consola y anda sin problema. Al tratar de reinstalar el phpmyadmin me indica que ya está instalado en su versión más reciente, pero el servidor me dice que no lo encuentra